# Get Mysql execution time of last query by using mysql only

Tags: mysql, performance

I am currently trying to optimize the performance of my MySQL application.

I have found a nice way to get the "cost" of the last query:

SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Last_query_cost';

However it would be somehow handy if this would also work for the execution time of the last query - apparently this seems not to be the case.

Is there a way to do this with MySQL only? - Without using the mysql workbench or PhP code or the like...

Comment: Note that the 2nd response contains the answer for the current MySQL versions.

Comment: If you're interactively modifying the query, you can also use the command-line client which shows the query time by default. Otherwise check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: That status is not what you want:  "The total cost of the last compiled query as computed by the query optimizer."